# Any statistics on how active this Meta site is compared to all the others?

Tags: discussion

This Meta site is pretty quiet. Surprised to see questions regularly getting about 6 'views'.

How does it compare to other Meta sites? I know the general Meta Stack Exchange is extremely active. But compared to specific site metas?